# Question about "Wer ist das da?" in German

Tags: grammar

When you want to ask a person "Who is this over there?", you would say "Wer ist das da?"

1. Can I use *da* to indicate both the person near to and far away from me?
2. Why use *das* here, why not say *Wer ist er/sie/es*?
3. How would I ask for more than one person? *Wer sind sie da*?

Answer (score 1):

"Da" can be used to refer to any location. It simply means *there* or *over there*.

So in response to your first question - yes.

In response to your second question: *Das* is used to ask about any person, gender doesn't matter.

> Wer ist das?

Means *who is **that**?* You don't need to specify whether it's a man or a woman you're referring to. It works for both sexes, and that's why you don't need to further distinguish between to the two. You *can*, but you don't need to.

If you want to ask about multiple persons, you'd go:

> Wer sind die da?

However, when referring to a group of people you commonly further clarify that, as in:

> Wer sind die Leute da?

Again, you don't *need* to do that though.